# Update DynamoDB nested map within a set using conditional

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to update an item in DynamoDB that has somewhat complicated(?) data structure.

Item:

```
{
    'user_id': 'abc123',
    'groups': [
        {
            'group_id': 'Group1',
            'games_won': [],
            'games_lost': []
        },
        {
            'group_id': 'Group2',
            'games_won': [],
            'games_lost': []
        },
    ]
}
```

I am trying to append a string to `games_won` on a specific group_id. I am trying to use a conditional to avoid multiple db queries but I can't seem to figure out how to iterate over `groups` in my conditional.

Basically, I want to do this:

```
for g in groups:
    if g.group_id == 'Group2':
        g.games_won.append('game12345')
```

Sorry for the complicated title. I'm a bit new to DynamoDB and NoSQL in general.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the 'groups' attribute, then change the data outside of the query and when your done write the whole thing back. That way no matter how many groups you change you always have just one read and one write action. The number of read or write capacity units consumed is off course related to the size of your 'groups' attribute.

Comment: That was my fallback plan. I was hoping there would be some way of constructing a conditional that I could use in an update statement that could combine it into one operation.

Comment: If anyone knows how to do it I'd love to hear it but I don't think that is possible. Also it doesn't really align with the keep it simple philosophy of DynamoDB I think. Sounds like something you could do in an Oracle query, but then again what can't you do in an Oracle query. ;)